# Date.now official format name

Tags: javascript, date, format

I read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) for the Date.now() method.
It's understood what it returns, and my question focus on, literally, the format name.

I have a REST call, where on of its properties is `expirtyDate`, and I wish to format to be as returned by the `Date.now()` method (i.e- the numbers of milliseconds passed from Jan 1970).

But how can I describe this format the my teammates? I can't tell them "use the Date.now() of JS". I prefer to ask them for "use  time format"

So how should I call this format?

Comment: You could always use the name in the language specification: [*time value*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-time-values-and-time-range). The documentation at MDN is a public wiki that anyone can contribute to. While it's very helpful, it's not authoritative and uses a lot of jargon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation you link to:

> the number of milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC

or

> the milliseconds elapsed since the UNIX epoch

AKA [UNIX time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), POSIX time, and epoch time).

Comment: Those are all “defined” as seconds from 1.1.1970 though - so the fact that milliseconds are expected, resp. the unix time would have to be taken times 1,000, should probably be explicitly mentioned to the teammates as well.